# Loadable/component React SSR throwing error on `getScriptTags`

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, code-splitting, loadable-component

I'm trying to set up SSR in my React app, which is using a private React component library, bundled with Rollup. Everything works fine, the app renders fine on the server, if I don't use `@loadable/component` and directly import each component.

I followed the tutorial for the SSR set up given [here](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/loadable-components/docs/server-side-rendering/) , and I'm using `craco` to override my CRA's webpack config, to include `@loadable/webpack-plugin`. I can see the stats file getting generated correctly. For my server webpack config, I'm excluding my component library from the `externals` option. I wrapped my app with the `ChunkExtractorManager`, and since I'm using Apollo, I first call `getDataFromTree(withmywrappedapp)` and then once this returns a result I'm trying to extract the script tags etc.

In server.js

```
  getDataFromTree(app).then(() => {
  const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString();
  const state = client.extract();
  const { helmet } = helmetContext;
  const scriptTags = extractor.getScriptTags(); // This throws an error
  const linkTags = extractor.getLinkTags();

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Html content={content} helmet={helmet} assets={assets} scriptTags={scriptTags} linkTags={linkTags} state={state} initData={initData}/>,
  );
  if (staticContext.url) {
    return res.redirect(301, staticContext.url);
  }
  res.status(staticContext.status || 200);
  res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
  res.end();

}).....`
```

Unfortunately when I try to run `getScriptTags` I get this error:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _sharedInternals.getRequiredChunkKey) is not a function
 at ChunkExtractor.getRequiredChunksScriptTag (myapp/node_modules/@loadable/server/lib/ChunkExtractor.js:264:68)
 at ChunkExtractor.getScriptTags (myapp/node_modules/@loadable/server/lib/ChunkExtractor.js:314:36)
 at  myapp/dist/server.js:64058:34
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

`
Any ideas on how I could fix this or what could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring `@loadable/component` and `@loadable/server` are on the same version fixed this for me.